# Strapi.io - Allow users to see specific content

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-management-system, strapi

I'm new to Strapi.io and see that it offers Roles and Permissions. I'm building a tool which allows specific users to see specific content that is tailored for them. Ideally, I'd like to be able to add a multiselect to the User content type. This multiselect will be populated with references to all of my content. For each user, I can then select the content which is viewable.

Is this possible within Strapi?

Answer (score 2):

The feature is already implemented in each Strapi project (>v3.1) it's available under the settings tab (link in the left menu) and then in the Roles section. With the Community you have 3 predefined roles:

- Super Admin
- Editor
- Author

For each role you can set wanted permissions for roles however, if you want a more granular system you'll need to upgrade your plan. Take a look at our [pricing page](https://strapi.io/pricing)

Comment: Interesting, thanks @soupette. My understanding was that this is an open source project.  The pricing you're referring to is for a hosted version, correct?

Comment: No it's to enable more features in your project, with don't have an hosted version.